# Flatness under reduction

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Suppose that $f : X \to Y$ is a flat morphism of schemes.  Is $f_\text{red} : X_\text{red} \to Y_\text{red}$ necessarily flat?  Are there any hypotheses that would guarantee this?

Comment: Isn't this true since $X_\mathrm{red} \cong X \times_Y Y_\mathrm{red}$ and the fact that flatness is preserved under base change?

Comment: Dear @Takumi, your formula is false. Indeed,  think of any morphism $f$  where $Y$ is reduced  but  $X$ is not: base change changes nothing and $X$ remains non-reduced !

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg Yes, sorry, I guess I was being stupid! But this formula works for $X \to Y$ smooth, for example, no?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**No !**
The result is not true: it may happen that  $f : X \to Y$ is a flat morphism but that  $f_\text{red} : X_\text{red} \to Y_\text{red}$ is not flat.

**A counterexample**
Consider $\mathbb A^3$ with coordinates $x,y,z$ and for $X\mathbb \subset \mathbb A^3$ take the curve defined by the equations $4y^3+27z^2=0,x^3+yx+z=0$  .
For $Y$ take the  subscheme of $\mathbb  A^2$ with coordinates $y,z$ defined by the equation $4y^3+27z^2=0$.
Note carefully that $Y$ is already reduced but that $X$ is not.
And finally for $f:X\to Y$ take  the projection $(x,y,z)\mapsto (y,z)$.
Now, $f$ is flat because it is finite and all its fibers have length $3$ .
However $f_\text {red}:X_\text {red}\to Y_\text {red}=Y$ is **not flat** because its  fibers have length $2$ above all fibers except the fiber over $(0,0)\in Y$ which is of length $3$.

**Attribution**
According to Gerd Fischer in his fine book [Complex Analytic Geometry](http://books.google.fr/books/about/Complex_analytic_geometry.html?id=Oa8ZAQAAIAAJ&redir_esc=y) (page 151) this example is due to the late Adrien Douady, the master of counterexamples.
However I could not find the original source.
This is not surprising: I witnessed several episodes where Douady stunned the audience consisting of some of the best complex analysts in the world (in Oberwolfach for example) with counterexamples which he found on the spot with lightning velocity.
I guess that, unfortunately, most of these counterexamples went unrecorded.

**Appreciation**
This is a very nice question, apparently not addressed in books about algebraic geometry, not even apparently (but I may have overlooked something) in EGA nor Stacks Project.

Comment: Very nice, much appreciated!

Comment: Excellent. I read the question and thought it was unlikely to be true, and hoped for an example starting with a flat $X \to Y$ with $Y$ already reduced and $X$ not. But even then it's tricky to make $X_{red}$ not flat!

Comment: I'm glad you liked the answer Tim and @Jake. Thanks for letting me know.